# WSDL Import switching between 2 classes for same function return

Tags: java, delphi, soap, wsdl

I am using Java and Delphi right now and am using a service class in Java that is to be used in a WSDL import into Delphi. The java code has a function in it that returns the type of NameAndID. NameAndID is basically just that, an object that stores an int ID and string Name. There are 2 different NameAndID's being used in the service though. One is *NameAndID* the other is *NameAndId*. They are created in different Java files but both are being referenced in different functions within my service. The problem I am having is when I import the WSDL and my service file is re-created in delphi the return type of my function will change between the the two different nameandid objects, like exampled below:

> **Import 1:**
>       getNameIDFromCAA() returns NameAndID
>
> **Import 2 :** 
>       getNameIDFromCAA() returns NameAndID2

This happens without me changing anything having to do with either nameandid object or the function getNameIDFromCAA()

I'm assuming this might be caused by having the two different NameAndID objects being used inside the same service with slightly different casing on the name of the objects but I wanted to see if anyone else can confirm or had experience with this type of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that it was in fact due to the naming of the two objects as I suspected. I renamed the one of the NameAndId objects and upon importing the WSDL everything was resolved and it's easily differentiating between the two. This is somewhat the behavior I was expecting due to the fact that delphi IDE is not case sensitive.

Comment: now that I think about it you're right. I guess I'm stumped again then as to why the function in delphi would be switching the type of the return then since both Java and XML would be case sensitive they should be able to differentiate between the two NameAndID structures. In Delphi the two structures are shown with different names (one ends in a 2 as shown in the example in my question) so it's clear it has been somewhat differentiated but still my function would end up returning the wrong NameAndID structure when the function in java made a clear reference to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the `Generate alias for the element of pure collections (-Or)` option in **WSDL Import Options** while you are importing WSDL in your Delphi project.

Now your IDE is not going to duplicate your objects with **ClassName** and **ClassName2** etc.